# Display Default Filter base on specific Select Option - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a select menu.

```
<select id="dd" ng-show='data != null' ng-model='search'></select>
```

and my other HTML contents

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in data | filter:search" ng-show="search">

    <div class="row">

        <!-- Country -->
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" >
            <p>[[obj.country]]</p>
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,[[obj.flag]]" alt="" width="30px">
        </div>

        <!-- Main Info -->
        <div class="col-xs-4" >
            <p class="company-name">[[obj.user.username]]</p>
            <p>[[obj.obj.phone_public]]</p>
            <p>[[obj.user.email]]</p>
            <a href="[[obj.obj.url]]">[[obj.obj.url]]</a></span> <span class="col span_2_of_6">
        </div>

        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right" >
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,[[obj.logo]]" alt="" width="100px">
        </div>

    </div>

    <br><hr>


</div>
```

I triggered the filter when the user change that select menu.

I'm trying to set USA as my default selection. So I did this in my JS section

```
$.each(unique_countries, function (index, value) {
    if(value == 'United States of America'){
        $("#dd").append($("<option value= '" + value + "' selected='selected' >").text(value));
    }else{
        $("#dd").append($("<option value= " + value + ">").text(value));
    }
});
```

So far so good, and it work fine - if I change/touch my select menu.

My goal is to **display the result of the filter** as I would have the select menu to USA as soon as landing on the page.

So far it didn't do that. You may see what I have here : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/0xj47wax/)

---

Result now :

[image]

Result I want it to be :

[image]

---

Any hints on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of adding selected attribute in the html loop,

add

`$scope.search = 'United States of America';`

and replace the html loop with just

```
$.each(unique_countries, function (index, value) {
    $("#dd").append($("<option value= " + value + ">").text(value));
});
```

working solution - https://jsfiddle.net/0xj47wax/1/

Comment: Now, my dropdown-menu is empty because of this `<option value="? string:United States of America ?"></option>`

Comment: Can you make it not empty ?

Comment: Any other suggestions ?